# django admin - overriding changelist_view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two admin class for two models which is app1 and app2. App1 will be the parent model of app2.

```
class App2Admin(...):
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        return super(App2Admin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)

class App1Admin(...):
    def get_urls(self):
        info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
        urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^(.+)/app2/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.code_view), name='%s_%s_codes' % info),
            url(r'^(.+)/app2/(.+)/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.code_view), name='app1_app2_change'),
        )
        return urls + super(App1Admin, self).get_urls()

    def code_view(self, request, app1_id):
        "View all app2 for a given app1"
        request.app1_obj = get_object_or_404(App1_model, pk=app1_id)
        return App2Admin(Code, site).changelist_view(request, {'app1': request.app1_obj})
```

My problem is in the URL. When I accessing the app1 I'm getting the correct url which is *localhost:/admin/app/app1/app1_id/* and when I accessing the app2 page that's where my URL messed up like this *localhost:/admin/app/app1/app2/app2_id/*

What I'm trying to do is to retain the both id of app1 and app2 in the URL something like this *localhost:/admin/app/app1/app1_id/app2/app2_id/*

I'm still confuse on how to customizing the changelist_view() handle properly my URLs.

Comment: Are you trying to confuse yourself by using names like app1, app2?

Comment: Nope. This is only a sample. App1admin is an admin for parent model and app2admin is an admin of the child model. Do I make sense? :(

Comment: Ah then this is an attempt to confuse everyone else